# Solution to a second order linear differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a problem where I can conclude my argument if I can show that
$$-y'' + (a(x) - c) y = 0$$
with $y(0)=y(1)=y'(1)=0$ has only the zero function as its solution. Here $a(x)$ is a positive function on the unit interval and $c$ is also positive.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with a good way to solve odes with variable coefficients and am wondering if an argument could be made that this problem only has the zero function as its solution.

Comment: This can't be solved without knowing exact form of $a(x)$

Comment: The initial-boundary condition is overdetermined. $y$ is in particular a solution of the IVP $y''=(a(x)-c)y$, $y(1)=y'(1)=0$. By Picard-Lindelöf the only solution is $y=0$.